# Rails 3, Form submitting to its controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

I'm new to Rails and I've just spent another hour Googling and not finding an example.

So I have a simple form that I need to submit to an API.  So I tried submitting it to the API directly but got advice that I do it in my app so I can do something with the results.  Anyway, here's my simple form:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'submit') do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :email, :value => "Your email address...", :class => "text", :id => "email", :name => 'email',
        :onFocus => "change(this,'#222222'); this.value=''; this.onfocus=null;",
                :size => "26" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :ref_code, :id => 'ref_code', :name => 'ref_code', :value => @referralid %>
<%= submit_tag "Enter To Win", :class => "button-positive submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Everything I'm seeing has forms that that use a model, I have no need to persist this data, just pass it on to the API.

So my thought was I just create an action in the home controller, where this page lives and have the action submit to it but I get a RoutingError and it's: No route matches {:action=>"submit", :controller=>"home"}

So what do I need to put in the Routes.rb? I tried:

```
namespace :home do 
  resources :submit 
end
```

No Joy...  I'm sure it's simple but I just can't find the right example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you should have a look at [the ruby guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), it's very well explained (but I don't think it talks about API) and it will save you a lot of time in the future, I swear.

Not sure what you mean but I see some wired stuff, so I hope to be useful, but if you're following some tutorials from the net let us know the link.

Basically what I do is always to call an action of a controller (MVC), following this way you should have a controller (?? `apis_controller` ??) and call one action of it.

So you want to use `form_tag` instead of `form_for` because you're not addressing a model, therefor you want to get rid of `f.` and use suffix `_tag` ([api](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.4/)).

```
<%= form_tag(send_api_path) do %>
<%= text_field_tag :email, "Your email address..." %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :ref_code,  @referralid %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :api_name, 'your_api_name' %>
<%= submit_tag "Enter To Win" %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in your `apis_controller.rb` you create an action `send` where you send and manage your request.

```
#apis_controller.rb
def send
  # TODO: your code here
end
```

Another thing is to set the routes, something like

```
#routes.rb
  match 'apis/send' => 'apis#send', :as => :send_api
```

I'm sure this is not 100% working code, but it should be useful

[How to call the api? I had I fast look and found this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113600/how-can-i-call-an-api-for-example-flickr-api-in-ruby-on-rails-newbie-question)

When you ask for help it's always good to attach the error you get, this makes it easier for people to understand the problem.